# Unable to deserialize tokens of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory ver 3.10 with higher version of DLL

Tags: active-directory, office365

We are currently using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory version 3.10.0.0 for Office 365.Now when we are upgrading the DLL to higher version, it is not deserializing  old tokens saved in db.Is there any way to migrate old tokens to new one that can be used with new dll?

Note: version 3.10 is now removed from Nuget.

Comment: As I recall the ADAL devs did change the token cache format at some point, and there was no way to use the old cache. I can't find anything about it easily on their GitHub repo, so you may want to file this as an issue over there to get an answer: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues

Comment: @JasonJohnston  Can i get source code of version 3.10?

Comment: If it's on GitHub sure.